# SQL - Call function with parameters within a Store procedure

Tags: sql, function, select, parameters

I have a situation like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), CONVERT(BIGINT, C1.cod_cta)), 
       C1.cod_cta, 
       C1.descripcio 
FROM   table1 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData' 
WHERE  C1.something = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), CONVERT(BIGINT, C1.cod_cta)), 
       C1.cod_cta, 
       C1.descripcio 
FROM   table3 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData' 
WHERE  C1.something = 1 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   table1 C3 
                       WHERE  C3.cod_cta = C1.cod_cta) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), CONVERT(BIGINT, C1.cod_cta)), 
       C1.cod_cta, 
       C1.descripcio 
FROM   table3 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData' 
WHERE  C1.something = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       C1.desc_cuenta COLLATE latin1_general_bin 
FROM   table4 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData'
```

And I need to Modify de last Select:

```
SELECT C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       C1.desc_cuenta COLLATE latin1_general_bin 
FROM   table4 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData'
```

The Field "ImportantField" may or may not have a mask. So, I've made a function to remove the mask if it is using one. My question is how can I call that function inside that select. The function needs some parameters to work. Those parameters are data from another table. I have in another table registered if the "ImportantField" is using a mask or if is not. So, in SQL words, I need something like this, but working ;)

```
SELECT C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       dbo.Removemask(C1.importantfield, (SELECT parameter1 
                                          FROM   table5), (SELECT parameter2 
                                                           FROM   table5), (SELECT parameter3 
                                                                            FROM table5)) COLLATE latin1_general_bin,
       C1.desc_cuenta COLLATE latin1_general_bin 
FROM   table4 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData'
```

The table from where I take the parameters has only on row.

Any Ideas how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!!!

PS: I'm really noob in SQL, be nice please.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? For example in postgres I can create a `Custom type` then my function can receive or return that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since table5 only contain one record, you can join it to your query without affecting the result. This give easy access to parameter value.
See example bellow :

```
SELECT importantfieldOriginal = C1.importantfield COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       importantfieldWithOutMask = dbo.Removemask(C1.importantfield, table5.parameter1 , table5.parameter2, table5.parameter2)  COLLATE latin1_general_bin, 
       C1.desc_cuenta COLLATE latin1_general_bin 
FROM   table4 C1 
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM   table2 
             ORDER  BY [date] DESC) C2 
         ON C2.somefield = 'SomeData' 
INNER JOIN table5 ON 1 = 1
```

"1 = 1" fake a relationship between table4 and table5 and since table5 only contain one record, it is like a 1:1 relationship. :)

Comment: is you want do a cross join 1:1, just include `,` do  ` SomeData , table5 `

Comment: Why wouldn't you just specify `CROSS JOIN table5`?  Just tell the query engine what you want.

Comment: I'm familiar with the "," but I found it easier for others to understand this way as they aren't familiar with it. Beside, I also read somewhere that it's deprecated... don't remember where tough.  @[Bacon Bits] About CROSS JOIN, I'm not familiar with this type of join. That is why I don't have reflexe to use it.  I admit it seem less weird.

All three syntax work and have the same execution plan.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, @[Bacon Bits] Can you be a little more specific about that? It worked for me, but if I can Improve the query, I'm interested. Thanks

Comment: just replace "INNER JOIN table5 ON 1 = 1" with "CROSS JOIN table5"